# print variables in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Newbie here. I am trying to print a variable in a procedure. The procedure can successfully run but I cannot see the output. My code is the following:

```
Declare 
  v_test varchar(15) := 'hi, everyone';
Begin
  dbms_output.put_line(v_test);
  dbms_output.put_line('hello world');
END;
```

Please note what I am using is PL/SQL Developer not SQL Developer. So both `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` and 'DBMS Output window (View->DBMS Output)...' do not work in my case.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see any issue in your code. It should run as well. Try reconnecting the session once again and run your code.

Comment: What window type are you using? What is the global preference setting for Oracle > Output > Enabled?

Comment: Also, this is a block not a procedure.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes, I've found the real problem. Please see my comment below. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the below code:

```
 Declare 
    v_test varchar(15);
 Begin
    v_test := 'hi,everyone';
    dbms_output.put_line(v_test);
    dbms_output.put_line('hello world');
 END;
```

Comment: You just moved the assignment of `'hi,everyone'` from the declaration section to the code body. I don't see how this will affect the output.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson check the scope of variable in PL/SQL,while calling above procedure in PL/SQL developer the engine could not find the value of variable if variable initialised in declare section.

Comment: It isn't PL/SQL Developer that 'finds' the variable or passes it to dbms_output, as the whole block is processed by the server. And the variable is certainly in scope. The OP's version works fine anyway. There is no such bug in PL/SQL Developer and I don't see how there ever could be.

Comment: I checked my script again. The actual problem is the output window was accidentally hidden.  The code above  and my previous code work well. I am new to PL/SQL Developer and I apologize for being careless. To avoid misleading any other users, I cancelled the accepted solution. But still, many thanks to you all!

Comment: It's an output tab, not a window, so I'm not sure how it can be hidden.